# Delay dropdown menu on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, delay

I have a dropdown menu that works fine, but I would like to delay the hidden so it doesn't hide immediately. Right now I have this code below, but it's not working

```
$('#courses-ul').bind('mouseout', function()
{
    var menu = this;
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        $(menu).parents('li').children('ul').hide();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: why dont you use delay() method?

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: Hi CapeStar, my HTML is something like this one: <ul id="courses-ul">
<li><a>link 1</a>
<ul><li><a>link 1</a></li></ul>
</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

use the `delay()` methode, like so:

```
$('#courses-ul').bind('mouseout', function() {
    $(this).delay(800).hide();
});
```